# App like default photo browser in iphone?

Tags: iphone, photo-gallery

i am developing a app which contains feature like default photo browser in iphone. I done some what similar to that. but after loading some(near about 10-15) images from remote server,i am receiving  memory warning.My requirement is loading image one by one. For this, on scroll view i am putting an images and increasing the contentSize of scroll view. it will work fine. but due to memory warning app quite.

Guys, any have any idea to approach for this feature which work similar to photo app without problem?

thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running out of memory because you're keeping the data for 10 or more images in memory at one time. You need to have more logic in your code that not only preloads and increases the scroll view's content size, but also removes UIImageViews from the scrollview (and thus from memory) as the user scrolls to newer stuff. (You can also save "evicted" images to the cache area on disk so if the users scrolls back you don't have to go to the server again.)

Comment: Thanks quixoto for good idea. Any sample code for this approach will much better for me PLZZZZZZZZ

Comment: Don't have any handy myself. This is the sort of thing that's very application-dependent. Keep around an array of the "pages" in your scroll view, use it as a queue, and bump off the the least recent one each time you advance.

Comment: I have implemented something like this. But it's not straightforward to get it good. If you start loading stuff while the user is in the middle of a slide movement, it will look bad because the slide will stutter. I'm doing some of the loading on background threads, but still there are many tweaks to get it good on all old and new devices. To make it easy for you, you could drop support for old, slow devices, and keep more "pages" in memory at once to minimize loading occasions. Then again someone might have a better solution... Apple's album app shows "preview" low res versions of images etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UITableView, it will request the images only when needed, and will automatically purge off-screen cells to save memory. It may not fit into the aesthetic for your application, though.